# Do we need to worry about maximum row size of 65,535 bytes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am developing a website and my DB is MYSQL.
Ok its been said that

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes.

Why this is highlighted? Do we need to worry about this?

Is there any performance issues exceeding this limit?

Is there any advantage keeping below this limit?

Why? Why? Why?

Comment: I guess the DB _not working_  can be considered a _performance issue_ :D  If you have a table that exceeds 64K please share!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should. Because that is how the default storage in INNO DB works.

However, please keep in mind that the values for LONG and BLOB are not stored "in the row" but outside of it.Therefor the size of a HTML does not contribute to the size of the individual rows.

For BLOB and TEXT data, the information is stored internally in a different area of memory than the row buffer.